# Java recursive extract of innermost parenthesis until no more parenthesis

Tags: java, algorithm

the string is 1a2a(3a4) then I am able to extract (3a4) & calculate it, let 'x' be the answer then substitute to main 1a2ax & calculate as normal (which is easy, I have done. ( a - add, s - sub, m - mul, d - div)

for above equation, I have done like this (works only if I have one set of brackets)

```
public class task2 {
private static double parseString(String str) {
    // declaring the operators' counters
    int a = 1;
    int s = 1;
    int m = 1;
    int d = 1;

    // splitting the string up into operands and operators
    double[] operands = Arrays.stream(str.split("[asmd]")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
    String[] operators = str.split("\\d+");

    // the rest is pretty much self-explanatory
    double total = operands[0];
    for (int i = 1 ; i < operators.length ; i++) { // note that i starts at 1 because the first item in operators
        switch (operators[i]) {                    // array is an empty string
            case "a":
                total = total * a + operands[i];
                a++;
                break;
            case "s":
                total = total * s - operands[i];
                s++;
                break;
            case "d":
                total = total * d / operands[i];
                d++;
                break;
            case "m":
                total = total * m * operands[i];
                m++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    String x= "1a(2a6a16)a9s88s77m9d5";
    System.out.print("Expression \""+x+"\" on solving gives answer as ");

    //To extract String with Bracket
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
    String y = null;
    while(m.find()) {
        y = m.group(1); 
    }
    String z = Double.toString(task2.parseString(y));
    int p = (int)Double.parseDouble(z);
    String q = Integer.toString(p);
    x = x.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");
    x = x.replace(y,q);

    // To call method to find value
    System.out.println(task2.parseString(x));
    }
```

}

But prob comes when an equation is

((1a3a(9s9s(10d200))s(10m100a(192s187))a10)d2d8)

, when I have to apply the recursive extract of innermost parenthesis until no more parenthesis, which I am struggling with.

firstly (10d200) extracted and calculated, let the answer be "P", the equation becomes ((1a3a(9s9sP)s(10m100a(192s187))a10)d2d8)

secondly (9s9sp) extracted and calculated, let answer be "Q", equation becomes ((1a3aQs(10m100a(192s187))a10)d2d8)

thirdly (192s187) extracted and calculated, let answer be "R", equation becomes ((1a3aQs(10m100aR)a10)d2d8)

forthly (10m100aR) extracted and calculated, let answer be "S", equation becomes ((1a3aQsSa10)d2d8)

fifthly (Td2d8) expression calculated.

Plz, Help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you show what you did so far?

Comment: Hi again. So what have you tried so far? In the other question you already got the code to evaluate your expressions (https://stackoverflow.com/q/44213894/5710637)

Comment: Hello @fafl , I edited thw question with code which works when expression has one set of brackets.

Comment: You had one problem, then you used regex, now you have two. Try to use a for-loop to find the characters, it will be much simpler.

Comment: have put my code in for loop, it doesn't works @fafl

Comment: please edit your answer to have all the code you currently have

Comment: Consider using the Shunting Yard algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: Thank you all  for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
while (there are parentheses left) {
    find first closing parenthesis;
    walk left and find nearest opening parenthesis;
    evaluate expression inbetween;
    replace expression with result and remove parentheses;
}
evaluate expression;
```

Edit: Just for completeness, this can be written in a compact way using peg.js: https://jsfiddle.net/mxLq9drm/2

Comment: on calculating ur javascript code answer is coming correct, but I don't understand js. @fafl is it ok to ask it in java?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java, this answer seems like it would be a lot better with only the pseudocode. If the JavaScript were written in a more generally-readable less language-specific manner, it might be a different story.

Comment: Thanks @fafl I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to always parse the content of the first pair of brackets:

```
stack s

for i = 0; i < len(text); i++ do
    if text[i] is openingbracket
        s.push(i)
    if next character is closing bracket
        pos = s.pop()
        res = parse(text, pos + 1, i - 1)

        text.replace(pos, i, res)  //update the string to parse
        i = pos + len(res)         //set i to the end of the newly inserted string
```

The basic idea is to store the indices of all opening-brackets in a stack. If a closing-bracket is encountered, take the string between the last opening-bracket (head of the stack) and the current position, evaluate the expression and replace it in the string. Afterwards update the current position in the string and proceed to parse.

Comment: Thanks @paul for a new logic, I didn't knew this.